# How to set iPhone lock screen background programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am interested to develope an app which will show quotes on the lock screen of my iPhone. I want app like following image.

[image]

I am trying to do it but not getting any idea. 
Please help me so I can start working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Toam pointed out, the SDK does not allow you to set the lock screen background. However, you can kinda-sorta get around this. If you're willing to play a little music, you can set your own images/text to the lock screen in playback mode. Details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8387406/716216

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, the SDK does not let you do this.